# Error 502 with OpenStreetMap Geocoding

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, error

I'm a fairly new user to QGIS. I've used OpenStreetMap to geocode small data sets (30-ish points) with no problems. Now I'm trying to plot 1100 points. I've loaded up a basemap and a polygon layer, formatted my CSV with location data (address, city, state), but when I try to use the 'Web Service Geocode' tool as I have in the past (see below image), I get the following error:
`Failure connecting to API: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway`

I was under the impression I didn't need an API key for OSM, but maybe I'm wrong?

[image: Geocoding input]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Nominatim (as it seems that you are), its [usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/) applies, mentioning things like "an absolute maximum of 1 request per second".

Comment: thanks for your reply - that's useful info. I tried it with a smaller chunk of the data set and it worked just fine, so perhaps there's some upper limit I'm not aware of. it seems odd to me that there would be a maximum of 1 request per second, as you mention, without them mentioning a max number of points, say. either way, I think you're probably right. thanks again!